# How to make python typing recognize subclasses as valid types when it expects their parent class?

Tags: python, class, typing, callable, subtype

Here is a minimal example of what I need to do:

```
from typing import Callable, Any


class Data:
    pass


class SpecificData(Data):
    pass


class Event:
    pass


class SpecificEvent(Event):
    pass


def detect_specific_event(data: SpecificData, other_info: str) -> SpecificEvent:
    return SpecificEvent()


def run_detection(callback: Callable[[Data, Any], Event]) -> None:
    return


run_detection(detect_specific_event)
```

Now I get a warning:

```
Expected type '(Data, Any) -> Event', got '(data: SpecificData, other_info: str) -> SpecificEvent' instead
```

To me it seems like this warning doesn't make sense, as SpecificData and SpecificEvent are subtypes of Data and Event respectively, so everything should be fine. Is there a way to make this work as I expect? My idea is to be able to then have something like:

```
class OtherSpecificData(Data):
    pass


class OtherSpecificEvent(Event):
    pass


def detect_other_event(data: OtherSpecificData, other_info: str) -> OtherSpecificEvent:
    return OtherSpecificEvent()

run_detection(detect_other_event)
```

so the `run_detection` function is as general as possible. Right now this gives the same warning as above.

Comment: The problem here is your argument type in `run_detection` implies that the callable passed should be able to work on `Data` and all its subclasses, but then you pass it a callable that says it cannot work on `Data`, it can only work on `SpecificData`. For example, suppose `detect_specific_event` used an attribute in `SpecificData` that wasn't available in the parent class. But `run_detection` is told that the callback it should expect won't do that; it is told it will work on `Data` and all its subclasses. So then why does the function it is passed require `SpecificData`?

Comment: It seems like you are expecting the parent class to act as a union of its subclasses, but it cannot, because the subclasses may have functionality which the parent does not. If `run_detection` can call the callback regardless of the datatype, then you are asking the function to require a callable to be more specific (only operate on the base class) than you want (operate on any subclass). As far as `run_detection` is concerned, the relation between the classes are irrelevant. An easy fix is to just use a `Union` of your subtypes. Otherwise, look up "composition over inheritance".

Comment: @Alkasm  I mostly agree, but...  the 2 functions here could work, with LSP in mind, if further data,**which are not appearing here** were all SpecificData.  But the OP’s code only shows wiring up `run_detection` which is what they asked about here, not how it gets Datas.  If next a `SpecificData` only generator is spun up then it would work.  But not if it emits `Data` events.

Comment: @JLPeyret indeed my comments make an assumption about what the OP intends to do, which may or may not be true. But since OP states at the end "so `run_detection` is as general as possible", the main thing to hammer home here is that `run_detection` expecting a callable on the base class is *more* restrictive, not more general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter sub-typing is opposite direction with return sub-typing.

- Return value is assigned from callee to caller.
- Parameter value is assigned from caller to callee.

And assign value should be more specific than variable's expected type.
For example:

```py
data: Data = SpecificData()  # okay
data: SpecificData = Data()  # not okay
```

So you should do:

```py
from typing import Callable, Any


class Data:
    pass


class SpecificData(Data):
    pass


class Event:
    pass


class SpecificEvent(Event):
    pass


def detect_specific_event(data: Data, other_info: str) -> SpecificEvent:
    return SpecificEvent()


def run_detection(callback: Callable[[SpecificData, Any], Event]) -> None:
    return


run_detection(detect_specific_event)
```

Comment: Thanks, that clears up why I'm getting the warning. Does that mean there is no way to define `run_detection` so that it can accept both `detect_specific_event` and `detect_other_event` from my example?

Comment: I think so.
Both functions need different specific types so you cannot generalize them.
I suggest to change `detect_specific_event`'s parameter type to `Data, Any` if you need generalization.

Comment: hum, sorry, without knowing that much about typing, that makes little sense conceptually.  from its name, I would expect that `detect_specific_event` wants a `SpecificData` and might have problems with more generic versions.  yet, to make typing happy your function signatures convey exactly the opposite meaning to a human reader.

Comment: @PetarChernev Create `T = TypeVar("T", bound=Data)`, then you can type `run_detection` as `(callback: Callable[[T, Any], Event]) -> None`. This accepts both `detect_specific_event` and `detect_other_event`.

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while to remember which piece of typing to use, but IMHO you want to use [cast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast)

Unlike its use in other languages, **cast(x,y)** doesn't **do** anything, but it does tell typing *consider y as a type x*.  runtime, it's a no-op, just returns y.

**Like compiled languages, if I read it, I would pay special attention to the code:  is that really going to work at runtime?  are the data types actually going to be correct?**:

- The duplicate closure with the LSP remark is appropriate if you can’t guarantee that whatever is generating data later is only going to hand out `SpecificData`s.  If you can, then casting would be OK. Your minimal example is missing that bit, but if you had shown what actual data was passing through `print(data)` then we’d known if LSP applied.

```
from typing import Callable, Any, cast


class Data:
    pass


class SpecificData(Data):
    pass


class Event:
    pass


class SpecificEvent(Event):
    pass


def detect_specific_event(data: SpecificData, other_info: str) -> SpecificEvent:
    return SpecificEvent()


def run_detection(callback: Callable[[Data, Any], Event]) -> None:
    return


run_detection(cast((Callable[[Data, Any], Event]),detect_specific_event))
```

Here, you've basically told typing, "accept my word for it" that `detect_specific_event` is a `Callable[[Data, Any], Event])`.

outputs of runs and type checks:

```
$ mypy test2.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
$ python test2.py
(venv)$   well your code says nothing.
```

change cast to the actual sig:

`run_detection(cast((Callable[[SpecificData, Any], SpecificEvent]),detect_specific_event))`

```
(venv) $@so.mypy$ mypy test2.py
Argument 1 to "run_detection" has incompatible type "Callable[[SpecificData, Any], SpecificEvent]"; expected "Callable[[Data, Any], Event]"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
$ python test2.py 
$ well your code says nothing.
```